# VirtualBox/Vagrant Not Working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox errors that stop Vagrant from starting. Both are installed. However, when I run:

```
vagrant up
```

I get the following

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Then I run:

```
VBoxManage --version
```

And get:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.0.4_LinuxMintr102546
```

All of this has already been installed and reinstalled in trying to get this error fixed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know and can't tell as you provided very insufficient detail about your VirtualBox installation -- but I can ensure you that Virtualbox works flawlessly without any tweaks on my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation.  I fire up a Windows instance every couple of weeks to test things.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox

Comment: Thanks Frederic. I tried this to no avail. Here is the output:
`Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.0.4 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-22-generic
Building initial module for 4.4.0-22-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-22-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/make.log for more information.
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules [ OK ]
* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
* No suitable module for running kernel found [fail]`

Comment: Dirk, here is what happens when I load Virtualbox:
`WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.`

I have done both and continue to get this error.

Output of "uname -r": `4.4.0-22-generic`